# Pycharm 2019.3 cannot auto discover suitable virtualenv?

Tags: python, pycharm

Before 2019.3, pycharm can auto discover suitable virutalenv and automaticlly set for the project.
For example, when I created a project named "sample", it will automatically use virtaulenv named "sample".
But in 2019.3, this feature disappeared.
how to make it back?